# Nginx caching generating duplicate cache with query string

Tags: nginx

I have setup nginx with apache2 on ubuntu successfully. I have one problem that nginx creating multiple caches for same content

like:

```
http://example.com/url1

http://example.com/url1?v=1
```

this url having same content, Please help me how can I tell nginx to serve from cache even if url has query string like

```
http://example.com/url1?v=1

http://example.com/url1?v=2

http://example.com/url1?v=3

http://example.com/url1?v=4
```

Comment: I means tell nginx to serve from cache even if there is a query string

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry I don't know about nginx. Hopefully someone will come along to help.